# How to fix 'Error: Error: Column [...]` must be length 69478 (the number of rows) or one, not 2

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, count

I used count function as a way to count rows in groups. It worked perfectly and all of a sudden it started to throw an error message.

I have my data frame AOPV which contains columns country and month. (and many more) and I wanted to create new df with just 3 columns -> country/month/frequency.

```
EVENTS_per_month = data.frame(count(AOPV, c("country", "month")))
```

It worked perfectly I don't understand what might be a problem.
It gives error: Error: Column `c("country", "month")` must be length 69478 (the number of rows) or one, not 2

> Did any one have similar problem?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using `count` from `dplyr` (you didn't mention what packages you're working with). If you look at the docs, you'll see that this and most other `dplyr`-based functions take columns as bare names, not character vectors. Without any of your data, we can't verify that anything more is going on, but this seems like essentially a typo since it's just incorrect syntax

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this:

```
EVENTS_per_month=data.frame(count(AOPV,country,month))
```

and error is gone. I will leave the most in caste some1 has similar trouble